# Expecting difference of dates in number of months and days?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have to find the difference between two dates in months and days. 
I tried Google, but I only found the difference in months and days. But I'm expecting difference in months and days.
Eg: 01 April 2013  and 07 May 2013 Then the result should be 1 month 6 days.
I want the code to be using only Java 6 provided api. It is recommended but not like Joda Time and other.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: well, AFAIK, there is no method in the standard API to acheive this in minimum code.  you will just have to play around with methods from Calendar class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not any provided api in Java to calculate the DateTime differences. You should use external api or do it yourself.

Check this link, there is a manual way to do it:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/

Comment: The example showing only days difference.but not months and days difference.

Comment: I know, that was just a simple example. You need to manipulate it yourself or use external api like Joda.

If I had time I would write an example.